# How to organize a solution to a problem in my local community?

Tags: physical-communities, community-organizing

I need some suggestions how to get my community interested in solving a problem in our neighborhood. I want to help my community but, I don't know how to help the community make the community better. I need some help to help.

In our community we have a mink farm. It attracts leagues of flies to our houses and has a very bad odor.

I came up with a solution: chickens.

How can I get my fellow neighbors interested in considering my solution?

I sent out a letter a couple weeks ago stating that we need chickens because they eat the flies' larvae and that will at least make the fly odor go down.

I have had no responses, period.

Comment: Community building is for people who organize and lead their communities.  This question is relevant if we can turn it into a "how can i get my community interested in solving a problem".  I will suggest some edits.  You probably will need to add some more specifics about your community to get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Couple thoughts.  Post a local ad asking for community volunteers to help with a cleanup.  However, homework has to be done because you need to consider the safety of the volunteers as well as how to properly dispose of everything.  I'd call the local waste management and see if they have any ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We need to understand more about ownership of the mink farm, the regulatory framework locally, and why the civic infrastructure is not working to really make this good.